# SQL merging rows with same time

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite

I am asking for help with my databse. I need a SQL query doing following.

http://shrani.si/f/2E/ge/2JXHBdq2/untitled.png

As you can see, that the time is equal in 3 rows, but the data is not in one row. What i want, is to make 1 row out of these.

http://shrani.si/f/3W/lZ/4NJJyHxf/untitled.png

Could u help me generate the query, if its possible? Or will i have to loop trough the databse and compare values and paste them together?

Thnx for your help!

Comment: How about adding a Group By Clause: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: I am looking into this article, but i cant understand him enough to make my query get the results. Can anyone else help me with this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
select breaks,date,time, max(field1), max(field2).....
from table
group by breaks,date, time
```

not sure if max will work but some, but try it.

Comment: What is the feedback you are getting. Does not work is not very descriptive